# Balanced quaternary

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof, number-systems

I was doing some research on representation of numbers, and I found out about Balanced Ternary base to represent numbers with only {-1, 0, 1}. I got the ideea of how to convert from decimal to Balanced Ternary base and vice versa. But what about Balanced Quaternary Base, using {-1, 0, 1, 2}. To represent 27 we do so:
27%4=3 (we put -1 and add 1 to 27/4). 6+1=7%4=3 (we put again -1 and add 1 to 7/4). 1+1=2. So we have the folowing representation: 2(-1)(-1)=2TT. 2*4^2-4^1-4^0=2*16-4-1=32-5=27. But what about -6? I thought of thinking about the first power of 4 greater than -(-6). That would be 16. We add -6 to 16 and get 10. We represent 10 like we done with 27 , just that we add T in front of the number. It will look like this: T22. I found out this is not right everytime, and I shouldn't do this type of conversion. My question is: how can we represent -6 in Quaternary Base?

Comment: Using a quaternary base is fine, but do note the you lose the uniqueness of representation that you get with base 3. For balance you need odd bases. For your example -6= (-1)*16 + 2*4 + 2*1

Comment: @ScottBurns Yes, it's like in my example: T22=T*(4^2)+2*(4^1)+2*(4^0)=-6; I want to make an algorithm to solve this, is there any way to do this except the method I found? (I can't really find anything on the internet about it). I mean for negative numbers.

Comment: For an algorithm I'd stick to positive numbers then negate at the end. As you only allow 2 and not -2, you then have to replace any $(-2)*4^n$ with $(-1)*4^{n+1}+2*4^n$. If you do this working up from the lowest index you are guaranteed to terminate.

Comment: @ScottBurns Thanks for this great ideea; I'll try to implement it and you will be the first to know if I succeeded ;)

Comment: @ScottBurns I made the algorithm and tested it on a computer. Everything worked well. Thank you very much for your response, if it weren't you I wouldn't have succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually method for fast multiplication of binary numbers which is best described through balanced quaternary. Of 2 operands, the second one is actually converted to balanced quaternary.

On computer you have numbers in binary representation already. By grouping each of 2 bits, we get quaternary represenation, but that is usual quaternary, with numbers {0, 1, 2, 3}.

For example, 141 = 10001101<sub>2</sub> = 2031<sub>4</sub>

Then we start conversion to balanced quaternary. Start from rightmost digit. If we see 0, 1 or 2, we leave it 'as is'. But 3 is converted to 1(-1), so we get 'carry' to the next digit. In the next digit we first add carry (if it is present), so we can get number 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4. As before, 0, 1, 2 is left 'as is', 3 is converted to 1 (-1), while 4 is converted to 10.

In our example, we begin with 1: no change, still 2031<sub>4</sub>

Next digit is 3, we convert it to 1 (-1), so we have 20(-1)1<sub>4</sub> with carry to next digit.

Now we process 3rd digit, '0'. We add carry, so it is now 1. So we get 21(-1)1<sub>4</sub>

At last, we have digit 2 which is left 'as is': 21(-1)1<sub>4</sub>.

Point of this representation is: multiplying first operand by (-1), 0, 1, and 2 are all very easy operations: we either invert all bits and add 1, or just set all zeroes, or leave number 'as is' or shift it left by 1.